# Synchronizing sqlite database from memory to file

Tags: database, qt, sqlite

I'm writing an application which must log information pretty frequently, say, twice in a second. I wish to save the information to an sqlite database, however I don't mind to commit changes to the disk once every ten minutes.

Executing my queries when using a file-database takes to long, and makes the computer lag.

An optional solution is to use an in-memory database (it will fit, no worries), and synchronize it to the disk from time to time,

Is it possible? Is there a better way to achieve that (can you tell sqlite to commit to disk only after `X` queries?).

Can I solve this with `Qt`'s `SQL` wrapper?

Comment: Why not a ramdisk, then simply copy it back every x seconds and in the teardown? Much better to deal with a file than to deal with queries imho. Ramdisk file could be retrieved even if the db fails. It's just a file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's assume you have an on-disk database called 'disk_logs' with a table called 'events'.  You could attach an in-memory database to your existing database:

```
ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS mem_logs;
```

Create a table in that database (which would be entirely in-memory) to receive the incoming log events:

```
CREATE TABLE mem_logs.events(a, b, c);
```

Then transfer the data from the in-memory table to the on-disk table during application downtime:

```
INSERT INTO disk_logs.events SELECT * FROM mem_logs.events;
```

And then delete the contents of the existing in-memory table. Repeat.

This is pretty complicated though...  If your records span multiple tables and are linked together with foreign keys, it might be a pain to keep these in sync as you copy from an in-memory tables to on-disk tables.

Before attempting something (*uncomfortably over-engineered*) like this, I'd also suggest [trying to make SQLite go as fast as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite).  SQLite should be able to easily handly > 50K record inserts per second.  A few log entries twice a second should not cause significant slowdown.

Answer (score 5):

If you're executing each insert within it's own transaction - that could be a significant contributor to the slow-downs you're seeing.  Perhaps you could:

- Count the number of records inserted so far
- Begin a transaction
- Insert your record
- Increment count
- Commit/end transaction when N records have been inserted
- Repeat

The downside is that if the system crashes during that period you risk loosing the un-committed records (but if you were willing to use an in-memory database, than it sounds like you're OK with that risk).

Answer (score 2):

A brief search of the SQLite documentation turned up nothing useful (it wasn't likely and I didn't expect it).

Why not use a background thread that wakes up every 10 minutes, copies all of the log rows from the in-memory database to the external database (and deletes them from the in-memory database).  When your program is ready to end, wake up the background thread one last time to save the last logs, then close all of the connections.

Comment: Because then I need to create the logs, remember which part of the log I already saved, maintain the background thread, and largely speaking implement synchronization myself. That's possible, but I want to avoid that.