# Database locked while trying to open multiple jframes

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jcombobox, locked

My problem is , while opening a jframe which is including different informations than my main jframe , when i tried to work on this jframe, for example inserting data to SQLite manager's database . But it's giving me Database locked error.I can insert data from my main jframe which i'm opening new jframes with jcombobox. I hink i know source but i dont know how to fix this. I think i need to close my main jframe which i open other frames. So sqlite database can storage this frames datas. Here i'll give to you how can i open jframes with jcombobox and how i'm trying to insert a data to database. Please help me or , leave a comment what're you thinking about this problem. Am i wrong with source idea or true. I need your helps guys. Thanks for reading.

1: This codes how i'm opening jframes with combobox.

```
public void comboselect(){

    int d =ComboBox_name.getSelectedIndex();
    if (d==0){
        CezalıUye s=new CezalıUye();
        s.setVisible(true);
        dispose();


    }



    if(d==1){
     DeaktifUye z=new DeaktifUye();
        z.setVisible(true);
               dispose();

    }  
    if(d==2){
     TatbikatForm l=new TatbikatForm();
        l.setVisible(true);
               dispose();

    }    



    }
```

2:This codes how i'm trying to insert data which i opened from jcombobox.

```
 private void cmd_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try{
     String sql = "Insert into cezalitablosu (KimTarafından,Kime,Neden,Kaçıncı,Tarih) values (?,?,?,?,?)";

     pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
     pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
  pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
  pst.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
  pst.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());




     pst.execute();

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kaydedildi!");

     }   

     catch(Exception e)
     {     
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);   

     }  



         Update_table();


    }
```

Comment: You might like to have a read through [SQLite in a multithreaded java application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707434/sqlite-in-a-multithreaded-java-application) and [SQLite And Multiple Threads](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)

Answer (score 0):

execute() can not be use for insert,update and delete.

For insert,update and delete always use

```
executeUpdate();
```