# How to set threading mode in SQLite Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite

I am using SQLite DB and I have multiple threads using a single connection. 
As per https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html I think I need to use serialized  mode.

**How can I set threading mode in Java? I mean method?**

```
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.setOpenMode(SQLiteOpenMode.FULLMUTEX);
dbc = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcPath,config.toProperties());
```

> Is there any relation between SQLiteOpen mode and Threading Mode ?
>
> SQLite supports three different threading modes:
>
> Single-thread. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is
>   unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.
>
> Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
>   threads provided that no single database connection is used
>   simultaneously in two or more threads.
>
> Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
>   threads with no restriction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707434/sqlite-in-a-multithreaded-java-application

Comment: @tuxdna that link suggesting me to have Share the same JDBC connection among all threads, thats what I am doing it now, But I want to make sure "Threading Mode is Set to Serialized", how can I do that? Sorry  If I misinterpret the answer link, but I am not sure how to set threading mode? in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link you posted:

> The default mode is serialized.

If you want to explicitly select the serialized mode (or switch back to it), then use `SQLiteOpenMode.FULLMUTEX` as is also described in the docs.