# Database file is locked (SQL Exception in Java)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, locked

In my code, whenever I call the following function, the database Emitter can be reached. The function basically extracts data from the databases and stores it in variables.

```
public void fillEmitterDataLists()
{
    EmitterStructVo emitter = new EmitterStructVo();

    try {
        stmt = dbConn.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Emitter;" );
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            emitter = new EmitterStructVo();
            model.emitterList.add(rs.getString("E_ID"));

            String pri = rs.getString("PRI_ID");
            String pw = rs.getString("PW_ID");
            String rf = rs.getString("RF_ID");
            String reps = rs.getString("Reps");
            String interval = rs.getString("Interval");

            Statement stmt1;
            stmt1 = dbConn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRI where PRI_ID = '" + pri + "';");
            model.priList.add(rs1.getString("PRI_Values"));

            int priType = Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString("PRI_TYPE"));

            rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PW where PW_ID = '" + pw + "';");
            model.pwList.add(rs1.getString("PW_Values"));

            rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM RF where RF_ID = '" + rf + "';");
            model.rfList.add(rs1.getString("RF_Values"));
            stmt1.close();
            rs1.close();

        }
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But if I execute the following code after calling the above function, it gives the error that the Emitter database file is locked. Whereas, if I don't call the above function before, the following code works without a glitch. So, clearly, the problem is with the fillEmitterDataLists() function.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:FssDb.db");
Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Emitter where E_ID = '" + name + "';");
```

Now I have closed all of the statements and result sets as suggested in the similar questions on stack overflow so I have no idea why it is still producing the exception.

Please help?

Comment: FYI : You are closing your `Statement` and `ResultSet` in the wrong way. Closing a `Statement` should (not all JDBC do it) close the `ResultSet` with it. So if `Sqlite` do it properly, closing `stmt1` will close `rs1`. The next statement would produce an error (I think). Note that this should be done propertly in a finally statement (or using `try-with-resource`)

Comment: Nopes, it doesn't produce an error. I am closing the result set after the statement at multiple places and it doesn't produce an error anywhere. I also removed the line closing the resultSet and that didn't help as well.

Comment: I never said this was the reason ... but if you want an answer, don't try to open a _file based database_ twice. If you don't close the `dbConn` from the method above and try to get a new connection with the second snippet, this will not be possible, only one `Connection` is possible at the same time. It is good to use a `Singleton` on an SQlite DB to prevent any problem

Comment: Oh thank you! This was the answer. Apparently, I have been creating multiple connections at a single time which were even working without an error. But this time, it refused to work.

Comment: This is unlikely but I never tried to open two connection simultaneously with SQLite. You could share the same reference of the connection.

Comment: That is what I did. I created a connection variable shared by the whole code. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707434/sqlite-in-a-multithreaded-java-application) about multithreading and SQLITE.

You can find out that **SQlite don't support multiple connections**. The reason is that whenever you ask for a connection on the DB, a lock is set on that file, you need to close the connection to release that lock. Only then you will be able to open a new connection.

So you either have to close `dbConn` provided in the method above, or simply share the connection.

I suggest you take a look to the [`Singleton pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to manage the connection properly.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is particularly nitpicking about file locking. Try closing the connection as well, so that every function opens its own connection, uses it and closes it afterwards. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511901/system-data-sqlite-close-not-releasing-database-file#8513453) helps you.

Comment: The link to the answer didn't help but closing the connection did. Thank you! :)